# Position two absolute divs next to each other without overlaping

Tags: html, css

I have this setup:

```
<div id="container">

   <div class="left"> 1 </div>

   <div class="left"> 1 </div>

   <div class="right"> 2 </div>

</div>
```

I want to position the `left` divs behind each other by using `position:absolute`. Works fine.

And I want to position the `right` div to the right by adding `right:0`. Works fine.

Problem is that the `left` and `right` div overlap each other. I don't want this. I want the left div to not overlap the content of the right div.

I cannot set a fixed width to either divs.

Please see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfpjm9k2/) for a demonstration of the issue.

Here is my CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.left {
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
}

.right {
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `position:absolute;`?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Are you open to alternatives to absolute positioning? With abspos you remove elements from the document flow. There's probably a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: `position: absolute` will always overlap. Use `float` if you want to have content that 'goes around' the content that is floated.

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, I am open to alternative solutions, however, note that I am using position:absolute specifically to align the 2 left divs behind each other as shown in the jsfiddle. Do you have another approach to this?

Comment: @JaimeRodas See the comment I posted about to Michael. I need the 2 left divs to be aligned on top of each other. I know that I can use float and play around with margin to align them on top of each other but that's never accurate depending on the screensize etc.

Comment: Have you tried to add `float: right;` to the .right div?

Comment: Why can you *not* set a width? Does something like this work: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/9tpw4tkn/

Comment: The problem is we don't know your desired outcome.  What space should the left take? What space should the right take? There's a variety of ways to accomplish what you are after, but we need more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with **Flexbox** and `position: absolute`.

```css
#container {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.left:last-child {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.right {
  background:green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-wrapper">
     <div class="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world </div>
     <div class="left">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">Don't overlap please</div>
</div>
```

Or **CSS Table** and `position: absolute`

```css
#container {
  display: table;
}

.left-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.left:last-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lightblue;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-wrapper">
     <div class="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world </div>
     <div class="left">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">Don't overlap please</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is a solution, Flexbox isn't very friendly when considering browser compatibility. Any other ideas? Thanks for the answer regardless.

Comment: Why you need support for IE 9 or less?

Comment: Not just that, doesn't work on android browser, some ios safari version for ipad etc. Trust me, I went through this journey just recently and it's a headache and should be avoided for the time being.